# MSSQL database table slow after first insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database table, let's name it `X`. `integer` columns and one `datetime`. Primary key is `integer`, `identity`, also it is the `clustered index`.

Selecting from the table till the first insert is fast. After the first insert (1 million row):

```sql
select count(*) from X - takes 2 minutes to run
```

I thought something is holding a lock on that table, but DBMO said nothing.
Running:

```sql
select * from X with (XLOCK) - 0 seconds 
select * from X with (NOLOCK) - 0 seconds
select count(*) from X - 2 minutes
```

What I am wondering is if something would hold a lock on that table then xlock should fail, right?

After I drop the table and recreate it, it is fast again... till the first insert.

All the other tables inside that database behaves "normal".

What could be the issue here?

Comment: How are you inserting? Individual inserts? Bulk inserts? Is there any order to what you're inserting? Are you using identity_insert? There are different things you could be doing that result in a heavily fragmented or padded index, which could explain the running time. It's also not clear what you're comparing to what, though -- obviously operations on an empty or near-empty table will be faster than a table with a million rows in it (`COUNT(*)` is never instantaneous as it has to actually enumerate records).

Comment: My insert is from another table with insert into X ... select .... from Y where ... No identity insert, clustered index is not fragmented at all.
I am comparing with a table with 36 million rows in the same database - count(*) on that table runs under 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan for the slow query, using [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) or similar?

Comment: So is the *second* time you do `SELECT COUNT(*)` after inserting fast then, or is it consistently slow? 2 seconds to count 36 million rows is excellent, but (on anything that's not a columnstore) really only possible if all the data is already resident in memory. Can you confirm execution plans of both queries are the same, that is, does the optimizer use the same index for the `COUNT(*)` before and after? (The clustered index is not the only thing that could be fragmented.)

Comment: @KetanKotak, I don't believe `SELECT count(X.primarykey)` versus `SELECT count(*)` will make a difference (unlike `SELECT *` returning unneeded columns).

Comment: @KetanKotak please don't proliferate this misleading information.

Comment: Without seeing execution plans this is not answerable. I suspect the queries are more complex than a simple `COUNT(*)`, especially given one of them is somehow reading 1 million rows in 0 seconds

Comment: @Charlieface : Yes, `count(*)` is just an example, real world queries are like : `select * from x where foreignid=# and isprocessed=0`, and @Jeroen Mostert, you were right, the table I compared with has a huge nonclustered index, with basically all the columns as included columns, so everything is in memory.

Comment: deleted previous comment after searched enough on net

Comment: OK now how about you give us the *actual* queries you're doing, with the *actual* table and index definitions, and share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. SQL performance issues are rarely generic, they normally need a lot of info to diagnose properly. This question is not answerable without this

Comment: Note that by "all the data resident", I don't (necessarily) mean all the columns. `COUNT(*)` will be satisfied by using the *smallest* index available, since that's the fastest way to do it. The speed of that is therefore dependent on what index ends up being used, and how fast reading that index is, and that in turn can change if you insert rows. Of course the same is true for other queries as well. From your statement, though, it now sounds as if you're comparing *different tables*, rather than a before-and-after of the same table, which makes it even more important to compare plans.